# Gitlab-ci помочь написать скрипт который пушит код в master ветку после успешного завершения тестов

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci

1. создать репозиторий в гитлабе и разделить его на несколько веток (mster, dev, pre-relase) dev   -  ветка разработки pre-relase - ветка подготовки к релизу master - ветка релиза
2. залить в ветку dev приложение с unittest'ами (можно взять с предмета "тестирование ПО")
3. создать файл CI/CD (непрерывная интеграция) в котором необходимо реализовать следующую логику:

   - 1. вы заливаете код в dev и тут нечего не должно происходить
   - 2. вы заливаете код в ветку pre-realse
   - 3. gitlab по средством CI/CD должен сделать тесты вашего ПО и если они проходят, то отправить ваш код в master

Comment: Задали вот такую вот штуку в универе, с первым и вторым пунктом вопросов нет, а вот с 3 проблемы, ничерта не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Файл CI/CD делится на *stage* и *job*. *Stage* определяют последовательность. С помощью *stage* выполняют обычно один тип работы (сборка, тестирование, копирование и т.д.). Если предыдущий *stage* выполнится с ошибкой (скрипт вернет не 0), то следующий не начнется.

На *job* могут быть наложены условия выполнения через ключевое слово *only*. У нас случай простой, поэтому просто указываем имя ветки *pre-realse*.

С пунктом три самая сложность, т.к. нужно выбрать стратегию как заливать изменения. Самый правильный делать `merge`, можно через `reset`. В моем примере я просто отправляю изменения из текущей ветки в ветку `master`.

```
stages:
  - test
  - push

test_job
  stage: test
  only: pre-realse 
  script:
    - my_test

push_job
  stage: push
  only: pre-realse 
  script:
    - git push origin pre-realse:master
```

Можно все действия выполнить в одном этапе, но это идеологически неправильно и ненаглядно.